# How to run mutliple tasks with reactjs render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to reactjs. My render method fetches data from database every time and it stops functioning of all other activities. it fetches data every millisecond but none of other functionalities are working such as setstate etc.how to fetch data from database and parallelly do other tasks such as setstate and assign data to database.I am using firestore so how can i simultaneously get data from database and setdata to database.

```
        db.collection(this.state.user.email).doc(this.state.hisemail).get().then(docr =>{
            // console.log(docr.data())
            const tempss=docr.data().messages
            // console.log("called")
            const tempe=docr.data().name
            this.setState({
                messages:tempss,
                namesf:tempe
                
            })
        })
        }
```

This is present in render method

```
submit=()=>{
        this.setState({
            messages:rew,
            namesf:nams
    
        },()=>{this.waiting()})
}
    waiting=()=>{
        // console.log(this.state.messages,this.state.namesf)
        db.collection(this.state.user.email).doc(this.state.hisemail).set({
            messages: this.state.messages,
            name: this.state.namesf
        }, { merge: true,
        merge:true });
    }
```

This is function called on onclick which i wrote already the function is called but setstate and db set is not working because of db method in render in the above code

Answer (score 0):

setState cannot be called in render function , because your component will re-render (component will execute render() function ) again and again, please use your logic on other lifecycle method, such as componentWillMount, componentWillReceiveProps, etc

You may refer to stateful component in react official doc, to understand this

Comment: Yeah I know that but I am writing a messaging app so the data should be fetched every second right. @rizesky

Comment: well if it is your case just wrap ur function in setInterval() function, add it to componentDidMount or componentWillMount (whatever you like) give 1000ms /fetch ,

Comment: Thanks it worked but i got a problem again the firebase post requests are filling the console and it is causing the increase in memory usage of tab.@rizesky